# Библиотеки для парсинга xml

Tags: java, xml, javax

Какие есть библиотеки для парсинга xml в объекты java.

Я использую

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Object.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            object= (Object) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(request));
```

и оно работает, но при запуске на проде возникают часто ошибки не совместимости и я хочу от этого решения отказаться. какие еще есть бибилотеки?

Comment: От несовместимости ничто не спасёт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень нравится STAX. Обрабатывает простыню xml последовательно и быстро с помощью двух интерфейсов. Один из интерфейсов работает на основании event-ов(начало тега, начало документа и т.д), он является оберткой над другим интерфейсом который в свою очередь работает уже непосредственно с тегами и их именами(если память не изменяет). Лучше всего работает как замена xslt и xpath, но помнится STAX как раз  и хорош тем что его можно также использовать в равной степени место JaxB.

Comment: можно какой нибудь пример xml string to java object

Comment: Пример такой же длинный получится, как простыня xml:) О какой равной замене jaxb говорит афтар ответа? Кстати простыня xml и с помощью jaxb может быть и распрарсена или сгенерена. Имеются кое-какие приемы.

Comment: @Sergey "Кстати простыня xml и с помощью jaxb может быть и распрарсена или сгенерена" -  да прям америка открыта. А ничего что автор запрос спрашивал об альтернативе, а не повторения данного, всем известного утверждения, про то как jaxb парсит xml? Вам пример нужен? Элементарно вбиваете слово stax в google и будет вам счастье. Если же вы не найдете, пишите новый вопрос и я с удовольствием отвечу.

Comment: @alexsafsafsd Ничего! А утверждение может быть не всем известным. Мне вот например оно не было известно. Коль скоро о других принято судить по себе, я грешным делом и про афтара подумал нехорошо, простите. И поспешил с ним поделиться своим открытием. А пример мне уже не нужен. Кое что сам придумал, кое что нашел (тоже сам). Но все равно спасибо за стремление помочь:)